# Can I force an app to download its data to the SD card?

Tags: external-sd, downloading, app2sd, motorola-moto-g2, app-data

I recently downloaded [Vrse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shakingearthdigital.vrsecardboard) for messing around with VR stuff. To function, the app needs to download 360 degree video "scenes". The files are relatively large; generally a few hundred MBs. I'm extremely low on space, and it won't let me keep more than one scene at a time. Is there anyway to force the app to store data on the SD card?

Alternatively, could I transfer the existing app data to the SD card, so that it could download the new data on internal memory? Will the app know where to find it if I do that?

EDIT: Device is a 2014 Moto G (XT1064) running whatever came stock  (I believe it's 5.1).

Thanks!

Evamvid

Comment: Yes if the phone supports. Or you can swap internal memory with external memory (assuming you have good external memory size). There are workarounds on the Internet. Please mention the phone information in the question and also tag it.

Answer (score 0):

But if you want to change the main device storage you can change that in settings→storage and then click on standard device storage

Comment: I don't have that option: I get the storage breakdown by category (Music, Movies, Apps, etc.), then the amount of free space on the SD card. Then, I get an option to move pictures and videos to SD, and options to unmount or erase the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

Google play store allowed people to change their download location to SD, but they removed it due to people sending them emails how their apps did not install correctly. The only way to do it is to root your phone and find a video on the internet on how to do it.

Comment: "*but they removed it due to people sending them emails how their apps did not install correctly.*" -- can you support this claim with sources?

Comment: My whole class used this technique, so did I. I also complained how apps would not open.